# Best practice for JSON response to Restful API call?

Tags: json, rest

I'm trying to ascertain what best practice might be for returning a JSON response for a Restful API call. I've read multiple blog and tutorial articles that offer different opinions.

One approach I've seen proposes that any Restful call return a JSON response that includes both meta data and result data, like the representation shown below:

```
// response to a GET that returns an array of elements

{
    "status": "success",
    "count": 2,
    "type": "LoadServingEntity",
    "results":[ {
        "lseId": 2756,
        "name":"Georgia Power Co",
        "code":"7140",
        "websiteHome":"http://www.georgiapower.com/"
    }, {
        "lseId":1,
        "name":"City of Augusta",
        "code":"1000",
        "websiteHome":null
    }]
}

// an response that reports an API error

{
    "status":"error",
    "count":2,
    "type":"Error",
    "results":[{
         "code":"NotNull",
         "message":"An appKey must be supplied",
         "objectName":"requestSignature",
         "propertyName":"appKey"
     }, {
        "code":"NotNull",
        "message":"An appId must be supplied",
        "objectName":"requestSignature",
        "propertyName":"appId"
    }]
}
```

Other articles poo-poo this approach. I'm about to start a new API project and I'd like to get feedback from experts about the best approach on this subject.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://jsonapi.org/ which provides a recommended specification for building a JSON API. The response should include both the data and metadata